# Ubuntu 13.10 USB Installation does not give Installation Type window

Tags: 13.10, usb, system-installation

*RETYPED FOR MORE INFORMATION*

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 (removing Windows and replacing it with Linux), but the window that asks if you want to Format the Drive, Install Alongside, or Something Else doesn't show up.

Instead, it shows a blank partition table (which is what you get when you select Something Else). Interacting with anything on it besides Back and Quit will give the error "Ubuntu 13.10 has encountered an internal error." I'm not at all sure what's going on, since I did a Dual-Boot with the same USB stick on a different computer. I tried to download the installer again, formatted the USB stick and put it back on. Still giving the same result, so it must be at the fault of either the computer or the HDD.

**Other Information:**

Using a USB Installer

Tried installing through the LiveCD, but nothing changes.

I attempted another Dual Boot on the same computer. Everything worked fine, but the final installation (after the keyboard setup and such was done) hung. I waited for a whole 6 hours before I decided to cancel. It then said installation was finished and needed to be restarted. Before I even get into the menu where I select the operating system, I get the "error: no such device xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx grub rescue: " problem so I couldn't boot into any OS. I formatted the drive, then ran Windows Boot Repair and everything worked out. Now I just want to replace Windows 7.

WUBI works, but I want to remove Windows 7 and keep Ubuntu, so that's not a solution.

Neither 13.10 nor 12.04 LTS work. The same problem happens.

**System Information:**

Manufacturer: Gateway

Model: Veriton M430

Type: x64-based PC

BIOS Version/Date: American Megatrends Inc. P01-A2, 4/21/2010

Processor: AMD Phenom II X4 820, 2800MHz

GPU: AMD Radeon HD 6670

RAM: 6144MB

Comment: Have you got a screenshot? I installed it recently (13.10 that is) and did not find this to be a problem for me.

Comment: @Magpie Yes, here http://imgur.com/a/6HYqk Sorry, I don't have enough rep points to put in post, joined just to ask the question. Also ignore the 2nd display, couldn't get Shutter to work.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the dialogue seems to be a little small to read what is written.

Comment: @Magpie click the gear to the top right of the image, click "show full resolution", then zoom in.