# Unable to installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: installation, 13.10, windows-8, uefi, troubleshooting

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391819/ubuntu-13-10-usb-installation-does-not-give-installation-type-window) is a duplicate of the thread, but I need an answer so I decided to open up another question.

So, here is my problem, I want to install ubuntu alongside windows 8.1. I boot up the ubuntu live demo, and even without it I get the same message. The installation goes great up until the installation type is asked. I connect to the internet, even if I don't, it's all the same. And the screen then freezes. I can't continue the installation. I just get these:

[image]

[image]

I really need help because I need the ubuntu up and running as soon as possible.
Please help me.

EDIT: I did everything as instructed in the links below, and still as if there is not a single hdd connected, can't do anything.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's a similar bug reported in launchpad as "[**ubi-partman failed with exit code 141**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/945027)". In which is says; **Installation fails if there are two operating systems on disk with one of them being Ubuntu**. Have you installed Ubuntu before or is this the first time?

Comment: Have you followed the procedure as mentioned in the answer of this question - [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835)

Comment: I was trying to do it on my own, so I didn't google much about how to install, instead I googled the problem I got and the only thing I got was the duplicate thread..
will try the guide, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause of the "empty disk" symptom you're reporting is a partition table that the libparted library doesn't like. On Master Boot Record (MBR) disks, this is often caused by stray GUID Partition Table (GPT) data or other easily-fixed issues; see [my Web page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/) or my [FixParts utility,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) which can often fix such problems automatically.

If you've got a new computer with Windows 8.1 pre-installed, though, chances are it's installed in EFI mode, which means it uses GPT by default, and the usual MBR problems don't apply. You could still have partition table trouble, but the repair will be different. OTOH, if you re-installed Windows 8.1, you could easily have leftover GPT data, which FixParts will remove.

If you need more help, more detailed information is required, such as the output of the following commands (in Linux):

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo parted /dev/sda print
```

Note that `gdisk` is not installed in an Ubuntu live CD by default, so you'll need to install it by typing `sudo apt-get install gdisk` before running the `gdisk` command.